# Unit test for service with Jasmine does not return data

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner, angular9

guys! I'm new in testing person and stuck with this issue. I'm trying to write the unit test for my service, which getting data from the server. Classical case:

```
import {TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {ShiftsService} from "./shifts.service";
import {Shift} from "../shift/shift";

describe('ShiftService - testing HTTP request method getShifts()', () => {
  let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [ShiftsService]
    });
  });

  it('can test HttpClient.get', () => {
    let shifts = new Array<Shift>();
    let shiftsService;
    let calendarMonth = new Date().getMonth()+2;
    let calendarYear  = new Date().getFullYear();
    shiftsService = TestBed.inject(ShiftsService);
    httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
    shiftsService.getShifts(calendarYear, calendarMonth).subscribe(response => {expect(response).toBe(response.length);
    console.log(response);
    });

    let apiRequest:string = '/api/shifts?year='.concat(calendarYear.toString()).concat('&month=').concat(calendarMonth.toString());
    const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(apiRequest);
    console.log(apiRequest);
    expect(req.request.method).toBe('GET');

    req.flush(shifts);
  });

  afterEach(() => httpTestingController.verify());
});
```

My method inside service file looks like this:

```
getShifts (year: number, month: number): Observable<Shift[]> {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.append('year', year.toString());
    params = params.append('month', month.toString());

    return this.http.get<Shift[]>(this.shiftsUrl, { params: params })
      .pipe(tap((shifts) => shifts),
        catchError((err) => this.handleError(err)))
  }
```

I got the error: **Error: Expected [  ] to be 0.** When I print out the **response** variable I got that it is empty! But I'm sure that this method works fine! It works fine in my app! Could you please help me to fix this issue ? How to correct my testing method to test the service ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the very end, you are doing `req.flush(shifts)` and `shifts = new Array<Shift>();` which is essentially `[]`. The flush is what you want the HTTP get request to respond with, in this instance it is an empty array.

In the subscribe, you are asserting `response` (`[]`) to equal `response.length` which is `0`.

Try this:

```
it('can test HttpClient.get', (done) => { // add done callback to be able to call it in the subscribe
    let shifts = new Array<Shift>();
    let shiftsService;
    let calendarMonth = new Date().getMonth()+2;
    let calendarYear  = new Date().getFullYear();
    shiftsService = TestBed.inject(ShiftsService);
    httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
    shiftsService.getShifts(calendarYear, calendarMonth).subscribe(response => {
       // we have to use toEqual because toBe does a deep assertion
       // but the array to compare to is in a different location in memory so 
       // toBe would fail
       expect(response).toEqual([]);
       console.log(response);
       // call done to tell the unit test you are done with this test
       done();
    });

    let apiRequest:string = '/api/shifts?year='.concat(calendarYear.toString()).concat('&month=').concat(calendarMonth.toString());
    const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(apiRequest);
    console.log(apiRequest);
    expect(req.request.method).toBe('GET');

    shifts.push(/* push a shift here */) // change the shifts array to what you want the server to respond with 
    req.flush(shifts);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The error disappeared but I'm still can't get data from server! response is empty!

Comment: Change `shifts` to whatever you want the response to be. We are mocking the response with `req.flush(shifts)` so whatever we flush will be the response.

Comment: I want to get array of shifts from the server... and I don't understand how it must be changed ?

Comment: When unit testing, we don't actually make HTTP calls. We mock them. When we `req.flush`, we are sending the mock response to the http call. So if you want an array of shifts, in `req.flush`, send an array of shifts. I edited my answer.